# Error when trying to use <skipCapturingStackTraces> with NHProfAppender in NHibernate Profiler

Tags: nhibernate, log4net, profiler, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Trying to follow https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn#Usage

I have the following log4net.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="NHProfAppender"
      type="HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHProfAppender, 
      HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernateLog4Net">
    <sink value="tcp://127.0.0.1:22897" />
  </appender>
  <logger name="HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHProfAppender.Setup">
    <appender-ref ref="NHProfAppender"/>
    <skipCapturingStackTraces value="true"/>
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

I get the following Error:

log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [skipCapturingStackTraces] to set object on [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory+LoggerImpl]

Can Someone explain why this error is received and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SkipCapturingStackTraces` is a property of the `NHProfAppender`, similar as the `Sink` property, so you have to configure it on the `<appender>` element.

```
<appender name="NHProfAppender"
    type="HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHProfAppender, 
        HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernateLog4Net">
    <sink value="tcp://127.0.0.1:22897" />
    <skipCapturingStackTraces value="true" />
</appender>
```